# Does any one have any idea on how to send an email notification to the Account Owner whenever a user is added to the Account Team?

Tags: account-teams

I want to send an email notification to the Account Owner whenever a user is added to the Account Team.

Answer (score 1):

neither workflows nor triggers support AccountTeamMember, there the only option would be to build visualforce page to maintain team members. the underlying controller would be responsible for sending out the emails

Comment: Or write a batch process that runs once a day and sends the emails for new Account Team members.